# Lightning error handler hiding and and stacking errors

Tags: lightning-aura-components, locker-service

I'm in the process of tracking down errors with my Lightning App, and I notice that I'm getting multiple errors that I need to resolve.

This video (in super low res) show's what I'm seeing:
http://makeagif.com/HSOBE0

Per discussion here: [LockerService not allowing subscribing to $A.logger](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/129894) it sounds like one option is to put `try/catch` around every method that I create. However, these errors are clearly being captured by the framework, but not sent to the console with a nice error message and stack trace.

Creating a video and watching in slow motion to capture these errors can't be the proper way to debug... is there an officially sanctioned Salesforce solution that I'm missing?